# Hover Event using JQuery

Tags: jquery, hover

I am trying to get a "marker" to move when the user hover overs a certain  here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#icondesc a").hover(function(){
            var cls = $(this).attr("class");
            $(this).siblings("p").hide();
            $(this).siblings("p."+ cls + "_qu").show();
            if(cls == "talk1"){
                marginleft = "415px";
            } else if (cls == "talk2"){
                marginleft = "535px";
            } else if (cls == "talk3"){
                marginleft = "655px";
            } else if (cls == "talk4"){
                marginleft = "777px";
            } else if (cls == "talk5"){
                marginleft = "893px";
            }

            $("#quote_marker").animate({"margin-left": marginleft});
        });
});
```

and here's what my icondescription div looks like

```
`
<div id="icondesc">

                    <a class="talk5" href="services/solutions/index.php#energyanchor">
                    <img src="img/homeblue.png" alt="homeicon" class="icons">
                    </a><a class="talk4" href="services/solutions/index.php#fleetanchor">
                    <img src="img/truckblue.png" alt="fleeticon" class="icons">
                    </a><a class="talk3" href="services/solutions/index.php#medicalanchor">
                    <img src="img/medicalblue.png" alt="medicon" class="icons">
                    </a><a class="talk2" href="services/solutions/index.php#deviceanchor">
                    <img src="img/radioblue.png" class="icons" alt="radioicon">
                    </a><a class="talk1" href="services/solutions/index.php#transanchor">
                    <img src="img/busblue.png" class="icons" alt="transicon">
                    </a>

<p class="talk1_qu">Transportation</p>
<p class="talk2_qu" style="display:none;">Devices</p>
<p class="talk3_qu" style="display:none;">Medical</p>
<p class="talk4_qu" style="display:none;">Fleet Management</p>
<p class="talk5_qu" style="display:none;">Energy</p>

<span id="quote_marker"></span>
</div>
`
```

So, quote_marker just has a background-image and the margin-left IS defined in the CSS. Also, Position is set to absolute.

firebug is telling me marginleft is not defined. any advice would help!

Comment: have you checked what is in cls?  perhaps adding a case else statement would be useful for testing?  also, a console.log(cls) could help

Comment: Using the code you provided, it works for me in Firefox. http://jsfiddle.net/dxZnT/ (no images, of course)

Comment: I installed firefox on a mac (this is a pc) and ran the code and the quote marker is not animating with the hover. The paragraph text is changing but quote marker is not moving.

Comment: `cls` is defined in the jsFiddle I posted, and the marker is moving. Was the jsFiddle working for you? I'm using the latest Firefox on Mac.

Comment: Strange. Of course, the only evidence of it moving will be the scrollbar changing. Here's an update where I gave `hover()` its second function (it is meant to have two) that returns the margin to 0. Also, I placed an "X" to give the marker some visibility. http://jsfiddle.net/dxZnT/2/

Comment: Ok so It appears cls and marginleft is being defined, but the pointer isn't moving, thanks for your efforts by the way patrick

Comment: The pointer doesn't move in jsFiddle? Because it does for me.

Comment: Yes the pointer does move in JsFiddle in FireFox

Comment: The jsFiddle code comes from the code you posted (except for my modifications to make it more visual). If it doesn't work on your page, then there's something else wrong that you didn't post. If Firefox tells you that `cls` is undefined, then it is likely a problem with your selector: `$("#icondesc a")` not being correct for your HTML. Did you make any changes before posting your code here?

Comment: cls and marginleft is now being defined in firebug, evidenced via the console.log, I have tried adding in the second parameter for the hover function like you suggested but to no avail, I haven't changed anything else, what i don't understand is why would it work in chrome but not firefox?

Comment: If in your page, `cls` and `marginleft` are properly defined, and the pointer still doesn't move then there's some other issue that I wouldn't be able to tell what is wrong without seeing the rest of your code. Could be CSS? Could be something else. The second parameter for `hover()` was just to help out in jsFiddle. Although, if you don't want any code to fire when you `mouseleave`, you shouldn't use `hover()`. Use `mouseenter()` instead.

Comment: I'll take a look at the link.

Comment: I have a timed slider on the same page, could that be interfering?

Comment: If you can, use the latest version of jQuery, 1.4.2 instead of 1.3.2. Not sure this matters. I appended a script to my local copy of your page, but instead of `.animate({'margin-left':...` I did `.animate({marginLeft':...` and for some reason, it worked. First do the jQuery update, then try the new `animate()`.

Comment: I updated the demo (http://jsfiddle.net/dxZnT/3/). Using class may not be the best idea with your code, extra spaces, another class and your equality is out the window, which may be why you were getting an undefined marginleft because you don't have a default marginleft value. I added a `match` to grab the number and a `stop()` before the `animate`... see if that works for you.

Comment: Patrick you were correct with using marginLeft instead of "margin-left" you should copy this into your answer so that I can give you credit for it, thank you sir, you've been a huge help.

Comment: @Pete - Thanks. I posted the answer. Glad you got it working! :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing the hosted page, it appears as though using `marginLeft` instead of `'margin-left'` fixes the problem.

You're also using jQuery 1.3.2 instead of 1.4.2. Maybe that factors in?

Anyway, I have no idea why that form of margin left doesn't work on your page when it does in jsFiddle, but that seems to be the fix.